# Following code executes before click event finishes

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dom-events

I'm trying to write a "relatively" general function for a single click file upload action rather than use the jQuery fileupload plugin.  All the individual steps work just fine if they execute sequentially but I'm having trouble in that the rest of my function executes before the user selects a file to upload.  I would very much appreciate any suggestions of how I can make my JS wait for my users:

Function:

```
function filePost(ev) {
  var anch = getAnchor(ev);
  var form = document.querySelector(anch.dataset.form);
  var fileInput = form.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

  fileInput.click(); //<- CLICK EVENT I WANT TO WAIT FOR

  var url = form.getAttribute('action');
  var reloadTarget = anch.dataset.reload;
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var prom = fetch(url, {
    method: form.getAttribute('method'),
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: data
}).then(function (resp) {
    return resp.json();
}).then(function (response) {
    if (response.is_valid) {
        var html = response.html;
    } else {
        var html = response.err_msg;
    }
    document.querySelector(reloadTarget).innerHTML = html;
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
return prom;
}
```

Comment: well than you have to bind to the change event and when the user picks something, execute the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to wait for `click`. You don't want anything to happen when a user clicks, you want something to happen when they *select* something. Using the input element you can utilize the events called `change` or `input` to provide this functionality.

[MDN inputFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

Check out the below example to see what I mean:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
console.log("do something with " + this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: I'm using the `click` event to trigger the filepicker.  Based on the MDN docs I imagine I would still do this to get the effect I want but wrap the rest of the code inside a `fileInput.addEventListener('change')` function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use callback.
Just like you use `.then`

If `fileInput.click()` doesnt return `Promise` (which cant be chained with callback `.then`), you can wrap click() in a function that returns `Promise`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. you may want to set the function for `upload` or `submit` event. which means when that event get triggered, the file already been picked. then you can go ahead handle the file in the function. you dont have to wait for user input there.
2. if you really want to know how to wait for a function to return something. there are two common way to do it

   - using `promise`

   `functionA(input).then(outputFromFuncA => {<this is functionB>}).catch(e => {errorHandle});`

   - using `async` `await`, just make `function filePost(ev)` as async function and put `await fileInput.click();`